# Firefox canvas.toDataUrl() returns empty/blank image

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, canvas, base64

Before I posted this, I've checked dozens of stackoverflow and even tried different approaches but I never get it right.

this is my first trial code. What it's supposed to do is to convert svg to png and then download it onload. it works perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox.

The svgcontent and canvas width / height have valid values. the 'fname' is the file name which has valid value also

```
var svgcontent = $(this).closest('.svg-divinner').find(' .svg-file')[0].contentDocument.documentElement;

var cheight = svgcontent.viewBox.baseVal.height;
var cwidth = svgcontent.viewBox.baseVal.width;
var svgText = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svgcontent);
            
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function (){
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = cwidth;
    canvas.height = cheight;

    var ctxt = canvas.getContext("2d", {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
    ctxt.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)";
    ctxt.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctxt.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    a.download = fname+".png"
    document.body.appendChild(a); 
    a.click(); 
    document.body.removeChild(a);
};
img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + encodeURIComponent(svgText);
```

So the code above did not work. Then I tried another option using callback, code is below. What the drawInlineSVG() does is to download the uri once callback has been made. I can't find where I referenced the drawInlineSVG but i got it here in stackoverflow too.

```
var svgcontent = $(this).closest('.svg-divinner').find(' .svg-file')[0].contentDocument.documentElement;

var cheight = svgcontent.viewBox.baseVal.height;
var cwidth = svgcontent.viewBox.baseVal.width;
var svgText = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svgcontent);
            
var ctxt = canvas.getContext("2d", {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
ctxt.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)";
ctxt.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var img = new Image();
drawInlineSVG(ctxt, svgText, function(uri) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    a.download = fname+".png";
    document.body.appendChild(a); a.click(); document.body.removeChild(a);
});

function drawInlineSVG(ctx, rawSVG, callback) {
    var svg = new Blob([rawSVG], {type:"image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"}),
    domURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self,
    url = domURL.createObjectURL(svg),
    img = new Image;

    img.onload = function () {
        ctxt.drawImage(this, 0, 0,canvas.width,canvas.height);     
        domURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        callback(this);
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

Both options did not work. It still returned the same old "AAAA" values

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAQ4CAYAAADo08FDAAAfiUlEQVR4nOzBAQEAAACAkP6v7ggKAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA…
```

Please, I'm no expert and I'd really appreciate some advice/help for this.

Edit: This is the SVG that I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.3, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 2000 2000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2000 2000;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#F7F7F7;}
    .st1{fill:#494949;}
    .st2{opacity:0.5;}
    .st3{fill:#00AEF0;}
    .st4{fill:#0A0A0A;}
    .st5{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st6{opacity:0.15;fill:#DDD545;}
    .st7{fill:#DDD545;}
    .st8{fill:#FAB9AF;}
    .st9{fill:#333333;}
</style>
<g id="floor_1_">
    <path class="st0" d="M871.87,1495.69c-176.64-128.92-171.47-134.33-233.38-174.9c-183.53-120.25-259.25-92.49-291.04-172
        c-29.35-73.41,28.86-112.95,61.32-298.59c35.52-203.16-20.47-234.32,22.88-308.25c72.09-122.94,233.45-47.95,591.23-144.94
        c225.93-61.25,267.63-119.9,370.66-86c147.45,48.52,219.06,220.31,271.82,346.9c64.34,154.37,146.38,351.19,66.81,500.54
        c-89.18,167.4-274.94,75.37-487.81,307.28c-56.65,61.72-98.45,128.11-173.89,133.35C1023.41,1602.35,987.57,1580.13,871.87,1495.69
        z"/>
    <ellipse id="floor" class="st1" cx="982.24" cy="1589.95" rx="723.12" ry="61"/>
</g>
<g id="Wall_and_debris">
    <g class="st2">
        <polygon class="st3" points="816.64,748.5 816.64,643.45 919.35,643.45 919.35,545.4 1397.91,545.4 1397.91,655.12 
            1502.96,655.12 1502.96,932.92 1306.87,932.92 1306.87,1021.63 1108.44,1021.63 1108.44,937.59 921.69,937.59 921.69,846.55 
            818.97,846.55       "/>
    </g>
    <g class="st2">
        <polygon class="st3" points="891.82,748.5 891.82,643.45 983.29,643.45 983.29,545.4 1397.75,545.63 1397.75,655.35 
            1502.96,655.12 1502.96,932.92 1307.08,932.69 1307.08,1021.84 1151.66,1021.63 1151.66,937.59 985.37,937.59 985.37,846.55 
            893.9,846.55        "/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="825.54" y="456.89" class="st4" width="692.6" height="3"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="864.4" y="1019.96" class="st4" width="692.6" height="3"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="1306.87" y="934.62" class="st4" width="250.13" height="3"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="864.4" y="934.62" class="st4" width="244.05" height="3"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="854.72" y="459.81" class="st4" width="3" height="82.39"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="1047.49" y="459.81" class="st4" width="3" height="82.39"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="953.78" y="942.87" class="st4" width="3" height="82.39"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="1019.3" y="1022.11" class="st4" width="3" height="82.39"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="1231.12" y="459.81" class="st4" width="3" height="82.39"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="1467.32" y="934.49" class="st4" width="3" height="82.39"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="1198.36" y="1026.69" class="st4" width="3" height="82.39"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="1392.65" y="1026.69" class="st4" width="3" height="82.39"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="1407.13" y="459.81" class="st4" width="3" height="82.39"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="1398.13" y="653.47" class="st4" width="153.91" height="3"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="773.34" y="642.04" class="st4" width="146.29" height="3"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="835.06" y="543.75" class="st4" width="660.6" height="3"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st4" d="M1025.9,1541.45H904.8v-71.57h121.1V1541.45z M907.8,1538.45h115.1v-65.57H907.8V1538.45z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st4" d="M1067.24,1520.6l-60.43-95.64l1.03-0.84l85.34-69.82l54.7,124.24L1067.24,1520.6z M1010.76,1425.6
            l57.54,91.06l75.69-39.49l-51.97-118.06L1010.76,1425.6z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st4" d="M1125.12,1547.81l19.67-71.45h164.17v68.5L1125.12,1547.81z M1147.07,1479.36l-18,65.39l176.88-2.84v-62.55
            H1147.07z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st4" d="M1389.32,1538.79h-54.95l-15.99-98.33l84.56,55.05L1389.32,1538.79z M1336.93,1535.79h50.2l12.28-39.01
            l-76.97-50.1L1336.93,1535.79z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="Plant">
    <g class="st2">
        <path class="st3" d="M395.47,1378.19c-41.29-2.56-76.29-37.9-76.56-67.69c-0.22-24.61,23.37-31,24.18-62.05
            c0.69-26.82-16.63-32.77-13.7-55.61c3.08-23.98,26.57-51.52,54.8-51.58c32.45-0.06,54.53,36.21,56.41,65.28
            c1.28,19.76-10.8,22.49-10.48,41.1c0.67,38.08,48.2,48.92,47.55,77.36C477.07,1351.11,436.12,1380.71,395.47,1378.19z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect x="392.9" y="1181.56" class="st5" width="2" height="216.78"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st5" d="M393.59,1256.61c-19.89-1.34-22.66-30.61-22.77-31.85l1.99-0.17c0.03,0.29,2.73,28.81,20.91,30.03
            L393.59,1256.61z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st3" d="M364.73,1396.73h57.46c5.63,0,10.11,4.72,9.8,10.35l-7.83,145.13c-0.27,5.06-4.35,9.08-9.41,9.28l-41.83,1.67
            c-5.37,0.21-9.91-3.92-10.2-9.29l-7.8-146.8C354.62,1401.45,359.1,1396.73,364.73,1396.73z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st5" d="M393.59,1332.36c-14.19-0.95-16.15-21.7-16.22-22.58l1.99-0.17c0.02,0.2,1.89,19.92,14.37,20.76
            L393.59,1332.36z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st5" d="M392.82,1300.94l-0.1-2c16.95-0.82,19.39-19.21,19.49-19.99l1.99,0.24
            C414.17,1279.4,411.47,1300.03,392.82,1300.94z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st5" d="M393.63,1356.54l-0.1-2c12.03-0.58,13.78-13.67,13.84-14.23l1.99,0.24
            C409.34,1340.71,407.36,1355.88,393.63,1356.54z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="Light">
    <polygon class="st6" points="919.35,545.4 665,568 674,1050 739,1182 1307.08,1021.84 1307,938 1502.96,932.92 1502.96,655.12 
        1398,656 1397.75,545.63     "/>
    <path class="st7" d="M1474.48,877.75l-28.22,1.73l14.54-16.43c0.41-0.47,0.37-1.18-0.1-1.59c-0.47-0.41-1.18-0.37-1.59,0.1
        l-14.54,16.43l-2.03-33.12c-0.05-0.83-0.76-1.46-1.59-1.41c-0.83,0.05-1.46,0.76-1.41,1.59l2.03,33.12l-20.08-17.76
        c-0.47-0.41-1.18-0.37-1.59,0.1c-0.41,0.47-0.37,1.18,0.1,1.59l20.08,17.76l-28.22,1.73c-0.83,0.05-1.46,0.76-1.41,1.59
        c0.05,0.83,0.76,1.46,1.59,1.41l28.22-1.73l-14.54,16.43c-0.41,0.47-0.37,1.18,0.1,1.59c0.23,0.21,0.53,0.3,0.82,0.28
        c0.29-0.02,0.57-0.15,0.78-0.38l14.54-16.43l2.03,33.12c0.05,0.83,0.76,1.46,1.59,1.41c0.83-0.05,1.46-0.76,1.41-1.59l-2.03-33.12
        l20.08,17.76c0.23,0.21,0.53,0.3,0.82,0.28c0.29-0.02,0.57-0.15,0.78-0.38c0.41-0.47,0.37-1.18-0.1-1.59l-20.08-17.76l28.22-1.73
        c0.83-0.05,1.46-0.76,1.41-1.59C1476.02,878.33,1475.31,877.7,1474.48,877.75z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M807.87,557.78l-28.26-0.85l15.97-15.04c0.45-0.43,0.47-1.14,0.05-1.59c-0.43-0.45-1.14-0.47-1.59-0.05
        l-15.97,15.04l1-33.17c0.02-0.83-0.63-1.52-1.46-1.55c-0.83-0.02-1.52,0.63-1.55,1.46l-1,33.17l-18.38-19.52
        c-0.43-0.45-1.14-0.47-1.59-0.05c-0.45,0.43-0.47,1.14-0.05,1.59l18.38,19.52l-28.26-0.85c-0.83-0.02-1.52,0.63-1.55,1.46
        c-0.02,0.83,0.63,1.52,1.46,1.55l28.26,0.85l-15.97,15.04c-0.45,0.43-0.47,1.14-0.05,1.59c0.21,0.23,0.5,0.35,0.79,0.35
        c0.29,0.01,0.58-0.09,0.81-0.31l15.97-15.04l-1,33.17c-0.02,0.83,0.63,1.52,1.46,1.55c0.83,0.02,1.52-0.63,1.55-1.46l1-33.17
        L796.26,581c0.21,0.23,0.5,0.35,0.79,0.35c0.29,0.01,0.58-0.09,0.81-0.31c0.45-0.43,0.47-1.14,0.05-1.59l-18.38-19.52l28.26,0.85
        c0.83,0.02,1.52-0.63,1.55-1.46C809.35,558.5,808.7,557.8,807.87,557.78z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M1139.38,632.94l-22.93,1.4l11.81-13.35c0.34-0.38,0.3-0.96-0.08-1.29c-0.38-0.34-0.96-0.3-1.29,0.08
        l-11.81,13.35l-1.65-26.91c-0.04-0.67-0.62-1.19-1.29-1.14c-0.67,0.04-1.19,0.62-1.14,1.29l1.65,26.91l-16.31-14.43
        c-0.38-0.34-0.96-0.3-1.29,0.08c-0.34,0.38-0.3,0.96,0.08,1.29l16.31,14.43l-22.93,1.4c-0.67,0.04-1.19,0.62-1.14,1.29
        c0.04,0.67,0.62,1.19,1.29,1.14l22.93-1.4l-11.81,13.35c-0.34,0.38-0.3,0.96,0.08,1.29c0.19,0.17,0.43,0.24,0.66,0.23
        c0.23-0.01,0.46-0.12,0.63-0.31l11.81-13.35l1.65,26.91c0.04,0.67,0.62,1.19,1.29,1.14c0.67-0.04,1.19-0.62,1.14-1.29l-1.65-26.91
        l16.31,14.43c0.19,0.17,0.43,0.24,0.66,0.23s0.46-0.12,0.63-0.31c0.34-0.38,0.3-0.96-0.08-1.29l-16.31-14.43l22.93-1.4
        c0.67-0.04,1.19-0.62,1.14-1.29C1140.63,633.42,1140.05,632.9,1139.38,632.94z"/>
    
        <ellipse transform="matrix(0.6517 -0.7585 0.7585 0.6517 -200.6956 948.7015)" class="st7" cx="932.54" cy="692.86" rx="9.63" ry="9.63"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M1437.92,742.69c0.24,3.12-2.1,5.84-5.22,6.08c-3.12,0.24-5.84-2.1-6.08-5.22c-0.24-3.12,2.1-5.84,5.22-6.08
        C1434.97,737.23,1437.69,739.57,1437.92,742.69z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M857.85,588.78c0.24,3.12-2.1,5.84-5.22,6.08s-5.84-2.1-6.08-5.22c-0.24-3.12,2.1-5.84,5.22-6.08
        C854.89,583.32,857.61,585.66,857.85,588.78z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M834.51,983.37c0.24,3.12-2.1,5.84-5.22,6.08c-3.12,0.24-5.84-2.1-6.08-5.22c-0.24-3.12,2.1-5.84,5.22-6.08
        C831.56,977.91,834.28,980.25,834.51,983.37z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M1150.54,977.83c0.29,3.85-2.6,7.22-6.45,7.51c-3.85,0.29-7.22-2.6-7.51-6.45c-0.29-3.85,2.6-7.22,6.45-7.51
        C1146.89,971.09,1150.25,973.98,1150.54,977.83z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M1502.54,813.83c0.29,3.85-2.6,7.22-6.45,7.51c-3.85,0.29-7.22-2.6-7.51-6.45c-0.29-3.85,2.6-7.22,6.45-7.51
        C1498.89,807.09,1502.25,809.98,1502.54,813.83z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M1083.2,546.55c0.24,3.12-2.1,5.84-5.22,6.08c-3.12,0.24-5.84-2.1-6.08-5.22c-0.24-3.12,2.1-5.84,5.22-6.08
        S1082.96,543.43,1083.2,546.55z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M982.47,475.62l-0.39-1.76l-0.55,3.06c-1.76,9.72-7.2,18.39-15.18,24.21h0h0c7.77,6.59,13.16,15.55,15.35,25.5
        l0.39,1.76l0.55-3.06c1.76-9.72,7.2-18.39,15.18-24.21l0,0C990.05,494.53,984.66,485.57,982.47,475.62z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M1041.61,983.29c0.24,3.12-2.1,5.84-5.22,6.08c-3.12,0.24-5.84-2.1-6.08-5.22c-0.24-3.12,2.1-5.84,5.22-6.08
        C1038.65,977.83,1041.37,980.17,1041.61,983.29z"/>
    <ellipse transform="matrix(0.6517 -0.7585 0.7585 0.6517 -23.6571 1164.4873)" class="st7" cx="1256" cy="608" rx="5" ry="5"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M1256.78,888.29l-0.42-1.91l-0.6,3.31c-1.91,10.52-7.8,19.91-16.44,26.21l0,0l0,0
        c8.41,7.14,14.25,16.84,16.62,27.61l0.42,1.91l0.6-3.31c1.91-10.52,7.8-19.91,16.44-26.21l0,0
        C1265,908.77,1259.16,899.07,1256.78,888.29z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M1339.86,623l0.49,2.24l0.71-3.89c2.25-12.39,9.18-23.43,19.35-30.85h0h0c-9.9-8.4-16.77-19.82-19.56-32.5
        l-0.49-2.24l-0.71,3.89c-2.25,12.39-9.18,23.43-19.35,30.85l0,0C1330.2,598.91,1337.07,610.32,1339.86,623z"/>
    <path class="st7" d="M1047.14,872.27l0.33,1.51l0.48-2.62c1.52-8.35,6.19-15.79,13.04-20.79l0,0l0,0
        c-6.67-5.66-11.3-13.36-13.19-21.9l-0.33-1.51l-0.48,2.62c-1.52,8.35-6.19,15.79-13.04,20.79l0,0
        C1040.62,856.03,1045.26,863.73,1047.14,872.27z"/>
</g>
<g id="Person">
    <path class="st8" d="M574.86,1015.74c0,0-6.86,21.33-8.38,37.33c-1.52,16,12.81,32.5,12.81,32.5l8.53-62.98l-13.71-9.14"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M536.76,767.35c0,0-106.67,117.76-86.86,163.05c19.81,45.29,127.24,93.61,130.29,100.71s5.33-32.9,5.33-32.9
        s-83.81-65.03-86.86-79.24c-3.05-14.21,89.15-115.21,89.15-115.21L536.76,767.35z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M621.07,1527.34l-36.89-2.72l1.38,38.7c13.54-1.69,26.56-6.41,39.49-11.6
        C616.69,1543.28,621.07,1527.34,621.07,1527.34z"/>
    <path class="st9" d="M640.5,1556.81c-7.49,0.13-12.34-1.97-15.44-5.1c-12.93,5.19-25.94,9.91-39.49,11.6l0.94,26.35
        c0,0,8.55,10.85,29.59,7.93c21.03-2.93,83.66-12.75,83.66-12.75S696.26,1555.83,640.5,1556.81z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M579.6,962.41c0,0,1.36,257.14,1.36,286.24s-2.29,282.17-2.29,282.17l44.19,3.81
        c0,0,40.38-231.72,40.38-255.31s56.03-262.56,51.79-279.94S579.6,962.41,579.6,962.41z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M843.09,1525.42l-36.96,1.82l5.02,34.13c13.92-1.26,27.92-4.9,40.73-10.81
        C840.09,1544.2,843.09,1525.42,843.09,1525.42z"/>
    <path class="st9" d="M865.63,1552.31c-6,0.85-10.46,0.04-13.75-1.74c-12.81,5.91-26.8,9.55-40.73,10.81l4.44,30.16
        c0,0,9.69,9.73,30.27,4.25s81.74-22.9,81.74-22.9S920.93,1544.51,865.63,1552.31z"/>
    <path class="st9" d="M756.96,974.2c0,0,28.19,169.95,48,242.2c19.81,72.25,38.86,320.5,38.86,320.5l-41.14,9.14
        c0,0-41.91-186.67-67.81-280.39c-5.73-20.74-39.14-99.97-66.06-168.33c-19.5-49.54-35.6-93.37-35.28-105.1
        C634.29,964.31,756.96,974.2,756.96,974.2z"/>
    <path class="st3" d="M619.11,717.68c0,0-16.03-0.89-27,7.15s-16.88,223.45-20.25,266.35s197.4,37.11,204.15,19.23
        c6.75-17.88-28.64-224.8-41.3-253.41S722.06,715,674.8,709.63C627.55,704.27,619.11,717.68,619.11,717.68z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M685.29,589.68c0,0,12.29,39.52,8.45,66.1c-3.84,26.57-13.83,34.75-39.19,36.8
        c-25.36,2.04-49.95-23.17-52.25-35.43c-2.31-12.27-0.77-54.51-0.77-54.51L685.29,589.68z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M625.03,688.31l1.64,34.09c0,0,50.29,3.81,56.38-12.95l-0.76-32L625.03,688.31z"/>
    <path class="st9" d="M664.01,623.35c0,0-10.41-16.29-15.86-5.39c-2.65,5.29,3.99,17.04,12.4,17.04c0,0,2.3,40.88-8.42,51.79
        c-10.71,10.9-32.91,7.5-36.73,7.5s-23.78-37.4-31.38-59.28c-5.83-16.8-14.92-46.34,6.2-48.38c0,0,20.95-45.51,64.63-38.7
        c37.27,5.81,46.03,29.17,45.72,33.53c-0.76,10.67-26.67,18.66-26.67,37.33C673.91,624.11,664.01,623.35,664.01,623.35z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M801.65,768.93c0,0,86.24,113.24,106.35,86.57c26.69-35.39,16.53-103.85,16.53-103.85l33.49-5.77
        c0,0,8.32,165.41-37.47,175.22c-59.46,12.75-160.43-109.14-160.43-109.14L801.65,768.93z"/>
    <path class="st3" d="M601.46,718.65c0,0-36.51,10.6-50.22,21.27c-13.71,10.67-26.67,31.24-26.67,31.24l44.95,56.38l25.14-19.05
        C594.67,808.5,615.87,749.96,601.46,718.65z"/>
    <path class="st3" d="M683.05,709.45c0,0,61.72-3.81,126.48,63.24l-32.76,61.72c0,0-34.29-25.14-58.67-40.38
        C693.72,778.78,673.15,732.3,683.05,709.45z"/>
    <polygon class="st1" points="433.14,644.68 1024.4,758.97 1019.83,775.73 428.57,662.21   "/>
    <polygon class="st1" points="331.04,718.59 422.47,742.97 473.52,575.35 376,551.73   "/>
    <path class="st8" d="M925.95,763.82c0,0-1.36-20.85,2.45-27.71c3.81-6.86,7.62,2.29,11.43,0.76c3.81-1.52,7.62-2.29,9.91-0.76
        c2.29,1.52,3.81,4.57,6.86,4.57s0.76-1.52,3.05,0c2.29,1.52,3.37,24.27,0.16,25.47S933.41,774,925.95,763.82z"/>
    <path class="st8" d="M913.5,755.26c0,0,9.56,19.71,15.66,14.38c6.1-5.33,1.46-12.05,1.46-12.05L913.5,755.26z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

---------------UPDATE---------------

So I was able to solve it by just setting the height and width attribute to the SVG file itself since the overall issue was (quoted from Kaiido)

> The browser can't set a height nor a width to the image it has to draw, and hence it can't render it to the canvas. (It is able to do an estimation in the document, since it can be relative to something, but not in the canvas).
>
> So the solution is to set absolute width and height attributes in your svg files

THANK YOU!

Comment: Can you show the markup of your svg? Does it have a width and height attributes set to absolute values (px)?

Comment: Thanks so I got it right, your problem is that your <svg> doesn't have `width` and `height` attributes set. FF can't guess what size it should get rendered on the canvas. The linked Q/A shows you how to workaround that, but in your case you don't even need to go through an iframe since your svg is already inline orignally.

Comment: Hello @Kaiido, yes I've added the SVG to my question. The SVG file(s) are actually uploaded to server and I retrieve them onclick. Which is why I use .viewBox.baseVal to get the original height and width of the svg file. Which then successfully outputs the height and width just like in this SVG which is 2000x2000

Comment: viewBox.baseVal is not the width and height. The width and height are attributes called width and height. You don't have either on your root element.

Comment: Thank you @Kaiido I'll go and check on it

Comment: Hi @RobertLongson, I need to get the actual original size of the svg since it's only embedded to the page dynamically so i relied on the viewBox

Comment: OMG WOW I GOT IT! Thank you @Kaiido for the link! :D I didn't follow the total instructions but I got the idea of FF not knowing the height and width